# Chrome/IE abort POST response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, firefox, browser

Chrome and Microsoft IE are aborting a POST response but it's working fine in Firefox. When I run a test through Fiddler I notice the POST headers in Chrome/IE do not contain `Cache-Control: max-age=0` and `Origin: ...` but are otherwise the same.

In Chrome when I press the submit button the POST is sent to the server, processed, and the client aborts the response. After a few reposts, the client finally accepts the response; however the server has already processed the request so it results in duplicate info. This never happens on Firefox, it just always accepts the first response.

It seems to only happen if the request is large (ie: contains a lot more fields for the server to process) leading me to think this has something to do with the time it takes for the server to process the request (in Firefox the request shows as taking about 9 seconds).

Is there something in Firefox that would cause it to wait longer for this response? Or vice-versa, something in IE/Chrome that could be making it end prematurely?

It may not be relevant but this is a Perl Mason site. The response headers in the page which has the form being submitted:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Aug 2018 19:08:57 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: ...; path=/
Set-Cookie: TUSKMasonCookie=...; path=/
Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 1990 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: If firefox fakes 9 seconds, you could try increasing the timeout value from 5 seconds

Comment: Just tried that but still seeing the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was Javascript on the page responsible for the reposting. A `setTimeout()` which recursively called its own function was continuing to be set even after the form data had been posted within the method.

In Chrome/IE/Edge the form submission would be POSTed and the function would continue to set another timeout calling itself. The subsequent call would again POST and abort the connection waiting on the original.

Firefox however would not repost although it too would continue to set and recall the function.

The fix was to add a flag to track when the POST was submitted and when set, to stop the timeout cycle:

```
function countdown(secs, starttime) {
    var d = new Date();
    if (!starttime) {
        starttime = d.getTime() / 1000;
    }
    var nowtime = d.getTime() / 1000;
    var timeleft = (starttime + secs) - nowtime;
    timeleft = Math.max(0, timeleft);

    var isposted = false; // <-- Added as fix
    if (timeleft == 0) {
        isposted = true; // <-- Added as fix
        alert("Time is up. Click OK.");
        var frm = document.getElementById("frm");
        frm.submit();
    }

    if (!isposted) { // <-- Added as fix
        timeout = setTimeout(["countdown(", secs, ", ", starttime, ")"].join(""), 1000);
    }
}
```